# Initialize map of enums to structures

Tags: c++, struct, enums, stdmap

In C++, I am attempting to initialize a std::map of enumeration values to structures.

In the header file:

```
enum ePrompts
{
    ePrompt1,
    ePrompt2,
    ...
};

enum eDataTypes
{
    eIntegers,
    eDoubles,
    ...
};

struct SomeInfo
{
    std::string text;
    eDataTypes type;
    float minVal;
    float maxVal;
};

std::map<ePrompts, SomeInfo> mInfoMap;
```

In the cpp file:

```
void SomeClass::InitializeThis()
{    
    // I would like to have an approach that allows one line per entry into the map
    mInfoMap[ePrompt1] = (SomeInfo){"text1", eIntegers, 2, 9}; //Error: Expected an expression

    // Also tried
    SomeInfo mInfo = {"text1", eIntegers, 2, 9};
    mInfoMap[ePrompt1] = mInfo; // works
    mInfo = {"text2", eIntegers, 1, 5}; //Error: Expected an expression
}
```

I am probably missing something very simple here, but I have searched through Stack Overflow quite a bit and not come up with any results of someone doing this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line had the right idea.  It just needs a slight change:

```
mInfoMap[ePrompt1] = SomeInfo{"text1", eIntegers, 2, 9};
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! With this change I am now getting  'SomeInfo' being red underlined with the error 'type name is not allowed'. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say.  I mocked up the exact code you have and I get no errors.  I'm using VS2015

Comment: I copied what I posted over to a new test project and am still running into the same errors. I am using VS2012 running .NET framework 4.5. Is it possible that this syntax is too new, or...?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  The 2012 implementation of C++11 wasn't complete.  I would suggest trying the VS2015 Community edition.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option for me. It is a very large project for the company I work for and we are stuck with what we are using. Thank you for the help though! I'll try to find some other work-around.

Comment: One option you have is to change the struct to a class and use the constructor to accept full initialization.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation))

> 3 Similarly, a **simple-type-speciﬁer or typename-speciﬁer followed by
>   a braced-init-list creates a temporary object of the speciﬁed type**
>   direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the speciﬁed braced-init-list,
>   and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue

So just write

```
mInfoMap[ePrompt1] = SomeInfo {"text1", eIntegers, 2, 9};
```